# Angular 9 prodution build sub-directory crash on reload, fix this for both apache and nginx servers

Tags: angular, apache, nginx, ionic-framework, server

Angular apps on production build crash on reload from a sub-directory. Say, https://example.com/contact and it works as expected but whenever refreshed the page, the page crashes. However, this phenomenon doesn't happen with the homepage.
To avoid this, there is HashLocationStrategy available. But this has its own demerit. This adds an # in the URL, so the URL becomes https://example.com/#/contact and apparently the URL looks ugly.

Some answers on forums say that this happens because angular serves routes from root URL and it could be fixed by serving requests from root URL however I have no idea how to do that.

What would be a good approach to fix the crash on reload issue without including # in URl? If this could be solved by serving rules, then please mention configurations for both Apache and Nginx.

Edit: this is the error:
`Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again. If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.`

Comment: What do you mean "crash"? What's the error? If it's a 404 error, it's just because you did not configure your web server

Comment: I have updated, please check

Comment: Ok, so it's a 404 error. How did you configure your website in your webserver?

Answer (score 0):

try this configuration

```
location / {
  root /usr/share/nginx/html; #set your root
  index index.html index.htm;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
```